# How should I explain this code type checking in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm confused, whether I can use [*Everyday Types*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-inference) to explain this problem?

```
interface IUser {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

function fn(user: IUser): void {}

const user = { name: 'bob', age: 18, height: 188 };
fn({ name: 'bob', age: 18, height: 188 }); // error!
fn(user); // no error
```

Comment: See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks

Comment: @ShivamSingla Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The error comes from Typescript telling you that you are creating a new object there with data that is not needed.

When you use an already created object that fulfils your interface but has another values, it could be a child class or another interface that extends your interface, so having extra items there is the wanted behaviour.

On the other hand, creating a new object on the fly with extra parameters is a sign that you think `fn` needs a different kind of object to work properly.

Comment: Thank you reply, I get  some useful information.